# UICollectionviewcell badge masked behind view

Tags: swift

I am using a [badge library](https://github.com/kiwisip/BadgeControl) to help with adding large amounts of badges to UICollectionViewCells however for whatever reason, the badge itself stays behind the view.

[image]

However, once I go into the view debugger, this is what I see.

[image]

This is the code for my collection cell. I've tried different values in relation to `maskToBounds` and `clipToBounds` to no avail. Along with `self` and `contentView`.

```
import UIKit
import BadgeControl

class cellView: UICollectionViewCell {

private var upperLeftBadge: BadgeController!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    roundCorners(corners: .allCorners, radius: 10)

    backgroundColor = .init(hexString: "#37495b")

    clipsToBounds = false
   // contentView.isOpaque = true
    //isOpaque = true

    layer.masksToBounds = false

    upperLeftBadge = BadgeController(for: self, in: .upperLeftCorner, badgeBackgroundColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9674351811, green: 0.2441418469, blue: 0.4023343325, alpha: 1) , badgeTextColor: UIColor.white, borderWidth: 0, badgeHeight: 20)
    upperLeftBadge.addOrReplaceCurrent(with: "1", animated: true)

    upperLeftBadge.animateOnlyWhenBadgeIsNotYetPresent = true
    upperLeftBadge.animation = BadgeAnimations.leftRight
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

Comment: Can you share how you use that cellView and your collectionview? I try to replicate your code but didn't face any problem https://imgur.com/a/jptnjpH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using this view extension on the cells view to round corners. Removing the reference to this, and rounding the corners via `layer.cornerRadius = 10` resolved my problem. Not too sure why this would hide overlapping views.

```
func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        layer.mask = mask
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this in your UICollectionViewCell class?

```
self.bringSubviewToFront(view: upperLeftBadge.view)
```

for notes `self` is your `UICollectionViewCell` I mean

Comment: `'view' is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level`